SQL errors when querying for something with apostrophes
I have the below PHP function that queries some custom database tables and outputs the result. This generally works great, except for when I put an apostrophe in the query; for example, "Men's" or "Women's" causes errors like below. How can I solve this? I'm a bit of a SQL novice, so I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong.
[03-Oct-2024 16:12:10 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's%' OR `description` LIKE '%Men\\'s%' OR `code` LIKE '%Men\\'s%') ORDER BY `titl' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM `83kg5a_activity_posts` WHERE ( `title` LIKE '%Men\\'s%' OR `description` LIKE '%Men\\'s%' OR `code` LIKE '%Men\\'s%') ORDER BY `title` ASC, `code` ASC made by do_action('wp_ajax_activity_list'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, ActivityPlugin\ajax_activity_list, activity_include, include('/plugins/activity-plugin/views/activity-list.php'), ActivityPlugin\get_activities

/**
 * Get activities, optionally with a query
 *
 * @param array<mixed> $options
 * @return array|null
 */
function get_activities(array $options = []): ?array {
    global $wpdb;

    /**
     * Get the settings
     */
    $settings = get_settings();

    /**
     * Convert query
     */
    if (array_key_exists("q", $_GET) && $_GET["q"]) {
        $options[] = [
            [
                "key"      => "title",
                "operator" => "LIKE",
                "value"    => "%" . $wpdb->esc_like($_GET["q"]) . "%",
            ],
            [
                "key"      => "description",
                "operator" => "LIKE",
                "value"    => "%" . $wpdb->esc_like($_GET["q"]) . "%",
            ],
            [
                "key"      => "code",
                "operator" => "LIKE",
                "value"    => "%" . $wpdb->esc_like($_GET["q"]) . "%",
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Convert terms
     */
    foreach ($_GET["terms"] as $data) {
        $options[] = [
            "key"      => $data["name"],
            "operator" => "=",
            "value"    => $data["value"],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Convert DOW
     */
    if (array_key_exists("dow", $_GET) && count($_GET["dow"]) < 7) {
        $options[] = array_map(function($day) use ($wpdb) {
            return [
                "key"      => "schedule",
                "operator" => "LIKE",
                "value"    => "%" . $wpdb->esc_like($day) . "%",
            ];
        }, $_GET["dow"]);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the query
     */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}activity_posts`";

    /**
     * Append the options to the query
     */
    if ($options) {
        $query .= " WHERE";

        /**
         * Append the options
         */
        foreach ($options as $data) {
            if (array_key_exists(0, $data)) {
                $query .= " (";

                foreach ($data as $value) {
                    $query .= " `{$value["key"]}` {$value["operator"]} '{$value["value"]}' OR";
                }

                $query = rtrim($query, " OR");

                $query .= ") AND";
            } else {
                $query .= " `{$data["key"]}` {$data["operator"]} '{$data["value"]}' AND";
            }
        }

        $query = rtrim($query, " AND");
    }

    /**
     * Convert age
     */
    $queried_min = (array_key_exists("age_minimum", $_GET) ? intval($_GET["age_minimum"]) : $settings["age_limit_min"]) * 12;
    $queried_max = (array_key_exists("age_maximum", $_GET) ? intval($_GET["age_maximum"]) : $settings["age_limit_senior"]) * 12;

    $min_query = "";
    $max_query = "";

    if ($queried_min !== $settings["age_limit_min"] * 12) {
        $min_query = " `age_minimum` >= {$queried_min}";
    }

    if ($queried_min !== $settings["age_limit_min"] * 12 || $queried_max !== $settings["age_limit_senior"] * 12) {
        if ($queried_max >= $settings["age_limit_senior"] * 12) {
            $max_query .= " `age_maximum` >= {$queried_max}";
        } elseif ($queried_max >= $settings["age_limit_adult"] * 12) {
            $max_query .= " `age_maximum` >= {$queried_max} AND `age_maximum` <= " . ($settings["age_limit_senior"] * 12);
        } elseif ($queried_max > $settings["age_limit_min"] * 12) {
            $max_query .= " `age_maximum` <= {$queried_max}";
        }
    }

    if ($min_query || $max_query) {
        $query .= $options ? " AND" : " WHERE";

        if ($min_query && $max_query) {
            $query .= " ({$min_query} AND {$max_query})";
        } elseif ($min_query) {
            $query .= $min_query;
        } elseif ($max_query) {
            $query .= $max_query;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the order
     */
    $query .= " ORDER BY `title` ASC, `code` ASC";

    /**
     * Log the query
     */
    if (WP_DEBUG_LOG) {
        error_log($query);
    }

    /**
     * Get all cached activities from the database
     */
    return $wpdb->get_results($query);
}


Using the wpdb::prepare() method is recommended for creating queries properly and avoiding SQL injection.
For a basic solution, use the addslashes() function, but this is not sufficient for preventing SQL injection.
See Mysql + php with special characters like '(Apostrophe) and " (Quotation mark).
